# Capture Content Type selected at creation

Tags: 2013, content-type, calculated-column

I am trying to create a column that capture which content type a user selects to create an item in a list at the time of creation. I would also like to prevent that new column from changing regardless if the content type is edited from what it was originally. Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[SPListItem.ContentType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.contenttype.aspx) gives you the content type used for the item. You can write an event receiver adding / added to read this value and store. Don't worry about any update event receivers. As you will be storing this information in the same list, column level security is not possible or is not easy! Try to hide it from views, etc.

Answer (score 0):

#### Write ContentTypeId to Text field

If you need a complex field like ContentTypeID you can use a Workflow to write it to a Text Field.

#### Get ContentTypeId in a VIEW

If you need the ContentType in a **View** you can extract it with [JavaScript in a Calculated Column](http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/How):

```
="<img src=""/_layouts/images/blank.gif"" onload=""{"
  &"var TR=this;while(TR.tagName!='TR'){TR=TR.parentNode}"
  &"var item=ctx.ListData.Row[TR.rowIndex-1];"
  &"this.parentNode.innerHTML=item.ContentTypeId;"
&"}"">"
```

*proof of concept, tweak it to your requirements*

#### Prevent ContentType Change in EditForm

Simply deleting the ContentType selector on the EditForm can be done
Either by editting the Form in Designer or adding a CEWP at the bottom of the Form.

```
var el=document.querySelectorAll('select[name$=ContentTypeChoice]')[0];
var TD=this;while(TD.tagName!='TD'){TD=TD.parentNode}
TD.innerHTML=GetSelectedText(el);
```

to replace the dropdown with the selected ContentType (Label) as text

*answer scoring appreciated*