# SharePoint 2013: Force the Newform.aspx form to show Content Type choices

Tags: content-type, newform

Is there a way to be able to have users select `Content Type` when on `Newform.aspx`?
It currently works when on `EditForm.aspx`

Comment: Have you searched at all?? * http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/126704/content-type-field-on-newform-aspx/154870#154870
* http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/157215/capture-content-type-selected-at-creation/159242#159242